# Javascript function returning number with two decimals...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point

I have a function to return points along a line and my return comes back with two decimal points...? For example, a return of my variable px will be something like -88.4029.032940598.

vx is the x vector and mult is the distance of the line plus distance to calculate the point.
Here is the operation that is returning these values:

```
var mult = parseFloat(mag + theUnit);
var px = coord_one.x_point + (vx * mult);
console.log(px);
```

Never have seen this before- I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Seems like one of your values is a string (it can only be `coord_one.x_point`) and you are performing string concatenation of two floating point values instead of addition. Convert the operand to a number first: `+coord_one.x_point` (why do you store the value as string in the first place?).

Comment: Actually, what Felix Kling said.

Comment: thanks guys- i've been looking at these articles and I think you're probably right. ugh sucks when you're blind to the obvious after staring at code for hours.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parseFloat the coordonexpoint as well as the vx*mult first